# Form returning not valid in django

Tags: python, django

In my django app I have a User model that has a Boolean field of is_manager.

User model in models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    can_assign = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

I've been trying to create an edit page in order for managers and users to be able to change some of their fields.

Regular users should be able to change their bio and title, and the managers can change the can_assign Boolean.

I have a form that deals with the logic of that in forms.py:

```
class EditUserForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        if self.user.is_manager:
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            del self.fields['can_assign']
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['title', 'can_assign', 'bio']
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def editUser(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.user.is_manager or request.user == user:
        #POST
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=user, user=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                redirect('user-page', pk)
            else:
                print('nope')
        #GET
        form = EditUserForm(user=request.user, instance=user)
        context = {'user': user, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'users/user_edit.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Access Denied</h1>')
```

template:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




{% endblock content %}
```

for some reason the form.is_valid() method returns False. I have no idea why.
I have tried to use the .errors method on the form and on the form fields. No errors shown.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: change your `print('nope')` to `print(form.errors)` and tell us what that says (or you might be able to figure it out from there)

Comment: form.errors return absolutely nothing. Weird thing though, in forms.py I have added in the super() method *args as well as **kwargs and now everything seems to work fine. Very weird... can someone explain that maybe?

Comment: Oh! I completely missed that. I think the `*args` is required because that's how you pass in the `request.POST`. if you would have an explicit key like `myform(data=request.POST)` it would have worked because it would be in the `*kwargs` .. So it was basically failing cause it was acting like you were just initiating a **new** form, not submitting one

Comment: Ohhhhhh! I get it now.  Because request.POST is passed in *args in ModelForm and when I create my own __init__ method I override that data right? Hopefully that made sense hahah

Answer (score 0):

" Oh! I completely missed that. I think the *args is required because that's how you pass in the request.POST. if you would have an explicit key like myform(data=request.POST) it would have worked because it would be in the *kwargs .. So it was basically failing cause it was acting like you were just initiating a new form, not submitting one –
Nealium
"